# GetThemeFont function not working

Tags: c++, mfc, fonts, themes, common-controls

I'm working on a custom header control `CMyHeaderCtrl` which is derived from the MFC class `CHeaderCtrl` and overrides the `DrawItem` method to do some custom drawing when the application is themed. At first I try to determine the theme font for header items, but it fails and `GetThemeFont` returns the result `'element not found' (0x80070490)`.

The application which uses this control is linked against Common Controls 6.
Here is some sample code:

```
void MyHeaderCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    if(IsThemeActive() && IsAppThemed() && ComCtlVersionOK())
    {
        if(HTHEME hTheme = OpenThemeData(m_hWnd, L"HEADER"))
        {
            LOGFONTW lfw;
            HRESULT hr = GetThemeFont(hTheme, lpDrawItemStruct->hDC, HP_HEADERITEM, HIS_NORMAL, TMT_CAPTIONFONT, &lfw);
            ASSERT(hr == S_OK);

            // ...          

            CloseThemeData(hTheme);
        }
    }
}
```

I also already tried other properties than `TMT_CAPTIONFONT` like `TMT_SMALLCAPTIONFONT`, `TMT_BODYFONT`and so on. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I've never had any luck getting GetThemeFont() to return anything other than E_PROP_ID_UNSUPPORTED (0x80070490), either. Although it's not explicitly stated in MSDN, the idea seems to be that GetThemeFont() would only return something if the theme defined a font different from the default for the particular part and state specified by the other argument. At least, that's what one MSDN blog suggests: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/06/02/614575.aspx

Given that, it seems that the correct approach is to try GetThemeFont(), and if that fails, try GetThemeSysFont(), something like this:

```
HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(wnd,L"HEADER");
if (theme != 0)
{
  LOGFONTW lf;
  HRESULT hr = GetThemeFont(theme,dc,
    HP_HEADERITEM,HIS_NORMAL,TMT_CAPTIONFONT,&lf);
  if (FAILED(hr))
    hr = GetThemeSysFont(theme,TMT_CAPTIONFONT,&lf);
  ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
  // Do something with the font ...
  CloseThemeData(theme);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It really seems to be that way. I also tried `CWnd::GetFont()` which returns the correct font for the control. Which function would you prefer: `GetThemeSysFont` oder `CWnd::GetFont`?

Comment: Looking over code I've written, I've generally relied on CWnd::GetFont() to do the right thing. When a theme appears that has different fonts in it, perhaps I'll have to go back to change the code ...

Comment: If a part/state defines a font, it's only going to be for the TMT_FONT property, not any of the values supported by GetThemeSysFont. At least that's what the return data from a theme explorer is telling me.